# Best practice: PID file for unix daemon

Tags: unix, daemon, pid

Is it considered best practice for the parent or child process for a Unix daemon to write the PID file (for the child).

Comment: What do to mean by "write the PID file"?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, when a Unix daemon starts, it forks and frequently creates a file containing the PID of the child process so that other programs can know what PID is associated with the running service.   Either the parent or the child must create that PID file containing that process ID of the child (thus writing it).  However both are aware of the process ID of the child (as returned by `fork` in the parent or `getpid` in the child), I'm wondering which _should_ write it.

Comment: Well, it depends... If the parent is a daemon manager then it is more naturally its job to do it in a **centralized** log. Now **independently**, the daemon can also log its pid somewhere in logs dedicated to it. There is no "best practice". Both can exists at the same time...

Comment: In daemons the parent exits shortly after forking the child, so it's job is not to log anything, and PID files have more to do with process management than logging anyways.

Comment: "In daemons the parent exits shortly after forking the child" not necessarily. "PID files have more to do with process management than logging" writing a PID in a file is logging.

Comment: ... http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155633/discussion-between-jean-baptiste-yunes-and-isabell-cowan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The actual daemon process (the child).

According to the `daemon` man page provided by the `systemd` package and viewable on a RHEL 7 (or CentOS 7) host by running `man daemon`:

> 12. In the daemon process, write the daemon PID (as returned by getpid())
>              to a PID file, for example /run/foobar.pid (for a hypothetical daemon
>              "foobar") to ensure that the daemon cannot be started more than once.
>              This must be implemented in race-free fashion so that the PID file is
>              only updated when it is verified at the same time that the PID
>              previously stored in the PID file no longer exists or belongs to a
>              foreign process.

You can also read the man page [on the internet](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/daemon.html#SysV%20Daemons).